# How to call a function n times with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, iteration

I want to call my function n times with multiprocessing (in order to save time) and save results in a numpy array:

```
num=N # number of trials
results=np.zeros([N,2]) # array of results (2 because function produces 2 results)
def f(): #function with no arguments because the process is based on randomness
    ....
    return a, b #results are float64 type
```

I want something like this:

```
for i in range(num):
    results[i]=f()
```

but using multiprocessing. Is there a way?

I tried this but not work:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(15) as p:
        for i in range(num):
            result[i]=(p.map(f,iterable=i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling the [`apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) method, which belongs to the [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) class, and by storing the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) objects in a list. You also need to remember to invoke [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.close) and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) methods. After all the processes have finished, you can collect the results from the `AsyncResult` objects. In the following example, the `f()` function will run 100 times in total, but at most 4 processes will be running at the same time (not counting the process that starts the other ones). I am sure the code can be optimized even further, but it may be a good starting point.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


def f():
    # you perform your calculations here
    result = 0, 0  # this is only for testing
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 100
    async_results = []
    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for _ in range(count):
            async_results.append(pool.apply_async(f))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    results = np.zeros([count, 2])
    for i, async_result in enumerate(async_results):
        results[i] = async_result.get()
    print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but I still have a problem and it's quite strange: if I put count=10 for example it works perfectly but if I put count=100 CPU and memory work at their maximum capacity (so it's good) but after this when they finish the code never stops and spyder freeze giving me no results and it's impossible to stop it! I have to turn it down by task manager. Any idea??

Comment: I think I need a way to limit the number of processes. In my first post, where I tried to use mp.Pool, I set 15 as a limit for CPU (or so I understand from the documentation) but here I don't see anything that sets a limit. Am I right? Is there any solution?

Comment: If you set the count to 100, it will start 100 processes at once, and they will be working concurrently.

Comment: ok but as I can see in the code you suggest you put count=15 and results as an array with the same row size ([count,2]) so I understood count meant trials. For my code I need to do 100'000 trials, so how can I modify the code to achieve this? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I might have an idea. I will edit the answer in a moment.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much, you saved me from a terrible headache!